# Error: Could not find 2 Android X assemblies, make sure to install the following NuGet packages: - Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, rider

Using Jetbrains Rider, I created a new Xamarin application. Because Rider creates a Xamarin application with an older version (4.4.0.991640), I upgraded Xamarin to the latest version (4.8.0.1687).

However, when I build, I get the following error:

```
Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(131, 9): Could not find 2 Android X assemblies, make sure to install the following NuGet packages:
 - Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter
You can also copy-and-paste the following snippet into your .csproj file:
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter" Version="1.1.0.1" />
```

I followed the instructions by adding the snippet to my `.csproj` file.

`ExampleProject.Android.csproj`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.8.0.1687" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="28.0.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="28.0.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="28.0.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="28.0.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="28.0.0.3" />
        
        <!-- Newly added -->
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter" Version="1.1.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then I:

1. Ran `dotnet restore` on the solution
2. Cleaned the solution
3. Built the solution

However, I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved the issue by:

1. Removing the dependency from the `.csproj` file
2. Installing the latest version of `Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter` (1.2.0) from the Rider NuGet tab

[image: Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter in Rider NuGet tab]

**Note:** I had to also install the `Xamarin.AndroidX.Palette` (1.0.0.5) package to resolve both build errors.

Comment: Works like a charm for VS for Mac aswell

Comment: Also worked on VS 2019 for Windows 10. Thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: in my case, closed visual studio, then deleted bin and obj in all projects, after restart the building successfully